# Arch interface is up but gets no IP address

Tags: networking, arch-linux, drivers

After a clean install of Arch I have no internet connection despite having internet access during the installation.

The network is wired connection through a USB adapter and has been tested to work. The interface is "DOWN" but even after `ifconfig enp0s20f0u2 up` no IPv4 is listed. I suspect some driver is not getting loaded. The output of `lsmod` while booted in the live USB drive is quite different from that while booted on the installed on the PC.

Where should I look?

Update:

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

fails.

Update:

```
systemctl status dhcp  # or dhcpcd
Unit dhcp.service.service could not be found.
```

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated. Use `ip link set <interface> up` instead. Also you haven't provided any information if you've configured DHCP

Comment: Note that in case the driver wouldn't be loaded, the interface `enp0s20f0u2` wouldn't exist. Your issue must be a different one.

Comment: "fails" is extremely broad. Please include the error message, or in this case the output of `systemctl status dhcpd`

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! Thank you so much @mashuptwice for guiding me!

```
# Boot from the USB.
mkdir /tmp/disk && mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /tmp/disk
arch-chroot /tmp/disk
pacman -Syu dhcpcd
systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
systemctl status dhcp  # or dhcpcd
Unit dhcp.service.service could not be found.
```

Indicates that you have no DHCP client installed.

You could do the following to get a IP address:

1. set a static IP
2. boot an Arch USB stick, chroot into your installation and install `dhcpd`